# Excel vba: Is it possible to initialise an array of dates in one-line with brackets?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and am having trouble initialising an array of dates on a single line using brackets.

I know how to do this with Variant data types:
`arrayVariant = Array("hello", "world")`
and with string data types:
`arrayString = Split("hello,world",",")`
and can initialise an array of dates by initialising each item individually:
`arrayDates(0) = #01/01/1900#` etc
but I can't find any way to initalise a date array on a single line. Is it possible in VBA?

Comment: What's wrong with `Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array(#9/9/2017#, #9/10/2017#)`

Comment: Nothing at all but I've had a lot of trouble understanding how arrays work in VBA and was wondering if I had misunderstood some basic principles! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same approach for the String type, but converting each value to Date type, using the **CDate()**:

```
arrayDates = Array(CDate("1/1/2000"), CDate("2/2/2000"), CDate("2/3/2004"))
```

By using this approach you manage to fill the array in one line.